# Mocking a function with Mockito throws different error than defined

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito

I have several tests with a mocked service which call the same function and in each test should throw a different error to simulate a different problem. I don't understand why one test works just fine and the exception is thrown, but in an identical test a NullPointerException is thrown.

```
class UserMutationTest {
    private UserService mockUserService;
    private UserMutation userMutation;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        mockUserService = Mockito.mock(UserService.class);
        userMutation = new UserMutation(mockUserService);
    }

    //This test works perfectly fine, DataAccessresourceFailureException is thrown and caugh
    //and then a BaseGraphQLException is thrown which is exactly what's expected
    @Test
    void loginDatabaseUnavailable(){
        when(mockUserService.login(anyString(), anyString())).thenThrow(DataAccessResourceFailureException.class);
        assertThrows(BaseGraphQLException.class, () -> userMutation.login(anyString(), anyString()));
    }

    //This test which is a copy/paste of the above test except for instead it's supposed
    //to throw InvalidInputException, but when called it actually throws NullPointerException.
    @Test
    void loginInvalidCredentials(){
        when(mockUserService.login(anyString(), anyString())).thenThrow(InvalidInputException.class);
        assertThrows(InvalidInputException.class, () -> userMutation.login(anyString(), anyString()));
    }
}
```

```
public class UserMutation implements GraphQLMutationResolver {
    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public UserMutation(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    public User login(String username, String password){
        try {
            User u = userService.login(username, password);
            return u;
        } catch (DataAccessResourceFailureException e) {
            //Database Unavailable
            log.debug(e.toString());
            BaseGraphQLException ex = new BaseGraphQLException("Database Unavailable");
            ex.addExtension("Database", "Unavailable");
            throw ex;
        } catch (InvalidInputException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        //If I add a catch for NullPointException here it is actually caught, which makes no sense to me.
    }
}
```

Code for InvalidInputException

```
package com.band.api.exceptions;

public class InvalidInputException extends BaseGraphQLException {
    public InvalidInputException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Full stacktrace

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Unexpected exception type thrown ==> expected: <com.band.api.exceptions.InvalidInputException> but was: <java.lang.NullPointerException>

    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertThrows.assertThrows(AssertThrows.java:65)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertThrows.assertThrows(AssertThrows.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows(Assertions.java:2920)
    at com.band.api.UserMutationTest.loginInvalidCredentials(UserMutationTest.java:87)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:532)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:171)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:167)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:114)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:59)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mockito.internal.exceptions.stacktrace.StackTraceFilter.filter(StackTraceFilter.java:32)
    at org.mockito.internal.exceptions.stacktrace.ConditionalStackTraceFilter.filter(ConditionalStackTraceFilter.java:23)
    at org.mockito.internal.stubbing.answers.ThrowsException.answer(ThrowsException.java:49)
    at org.mockito.internal.stubbing.StubbedInvocationMatcher.answer(StubbedInvocationMatcher.java:39)
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.MockHandlerImpl.handle(MockHandlerImpl.java:96)
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.NullResultGuardian.handle(NullResultGuardian.java:29)
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.InvocationNotifierHandler.handle(InvocationNotifierHandler.java:35)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor.doIntercept(MockMethodInterceptor.java:63)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor.doIntercept(MockMethodInterceptor.java:49)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor$DispatcherDefaultingToRealMethod.interceptSuperCallable(MockMethodInterceptor.java:110)
    at com.band.api.services.UserService$MockitoMock$583046591.login(Unknown Source)
    at com.band.api.resolvers.UserMutation.login(UserMutation.java:51)
    at com.band.api.UserMutationTest.lambda$loginInvalidCredentials$3(UserMutationTest.java:87)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertThrows.assertThrows(AssertThrows.java:55)
    ... 42 more


Process finished with exit code -1
```

I don't understand why one test would throw the correct defined exception, but another would throw a NullPointerException. If they both threw NullPointer then I would have somewhere else to look, but they don't.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Without you posting the trace, I can only speculate that the NPE actually occurs in the constructor of `InvalidInputException`.

Comment: @john16384 The constructor for InvalidInputException is just "super(message)". I've added a full stacktrace but your observation gives me a jumping off point to try and find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the line:

```
assertThrows(InvalidInputException.class, () -> userMutation.login(anyString(), anyString()));
```

Specifically, you can't call `anyString()` here, because this is the call that actually gets invoked. You can't invoke a function to be called with `anyString()` as parameters, you have to set real values. If you change the line to `assertThrows(InvalidInputException.class, () -> userMutation.login("", ""));` it should work fine.

Comment: This doesn't appear to change result of the test. Shown above is 2 tests, which only differ in the exception thrown, one of them throws the correct exception as defined, the other does not, and instead throws NullPointerException. If the parameters were the problem, it would fail for both tests cases, correct?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't appear to change the result of the test". It's either changed or not? Did the stack trace change at all?


As for the difference between the two tests, I've seen Mockito do funky stuff in certain case before. I would make the change I recommended in both tests, not just the one. Based on the stack trace, I'm fairly confident that the issue is with the fact you are passing that result to of `anyString()` to the `userMutation.login()` call. You can see issues with this in the lines that immediately trigger the NPE.